# opening tabs with javascript after 3 clicks

Tags: javascript, html, button, window

So what I would like to do is when I click the button 3 times it will open 100 random tabs. How would I do this? This is what I tried and I was unsucessful

```
 <script>
  counter = 0;
  document.getElementById('button').onClick = counter+=1;
  if (counter = 3) {
  window.open('www.youtube.com/')
  }
  </script>
```

I had a button called button. This code didn't work. So any ideas on how to get the button working will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *"it will open 100 random tabs"* - Why? That seems a rather obnoxious thing to do to your users.

Comment: it is a test, not deliberately for spam

Comment: *it is a test, not deliberately for spam* why don't you just open 1 or 2 tabs instead of 100?

Comment: It was an example number but yeah. i probably will do that as that seems like an easier amount of tabs to deal with

Answer (score 1):

you have a mistake in `if`. replace `=` with `===`

and also look at this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function myFunction() {
        counter++;
        if (counter === 3) {
            window.open('www.youtube.com/')
        }
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this open only one tab

Comment: It is a test, not delibretely for spam

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function from onClick as shown by @bearwithbeard is generally a bad practice. Here's my method of approach,

JS

```
var counter = 0
var the_button = document.getElementById('button');
the_button.addEventListener('click', increment)

function increment(){
    counter++
  if (counter == 3){
    window.open('http://youtube.com')
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="button">
 Try me
</button>
```

You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yv6zr4dp/3/)

**Edit:**
I don't really know why would you want to open 100 tabs *(other than trolling)* and browsers will most likely block it. That aside, you can use a while loop for that in case you still need too.

Comment: *"Calling a function from onClick...is generally a bad practice"*. Yep. Don't want to use bad coding practices when opening 100 tabs all at once...

Comment: Ok, so thank you for that i really appreciate it. So now I have the javascript (thank you for teaching me) i need to have it so i click an image 3 times and it opens up https://www.youtube.com. I cannot figure out how to do it. Also, i have an <audio> tag playing a sound when i click it so how can i call 2 functions at once?

Comment: I don't think you even know what you are doing. I really suggest you to actually learn javascript first.

Anyway, you can simply add an id of button to the attributes of your img tag and it will work. if you want to call another function you can simply add another event listener.

Comment: That is what I did, i added the id from the button to the img tag but it still wasn't working and that what stumped me. I haven't actually had the time to work on my JavaScript skills so sorry I apologise if I seem like a noob or have a very basic skill set. If you could point me in the right direction to master JavaScript (preferably a free option) that would be great.

Comment: There's no one way to learn Javascript. Many people have different learning strategy and approach. If you need interactive learning process, I really suggest trying codeacademy. Also, when you are asking "why my code is not working?" trying using jsfiddle.com to show it to people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to open 100 tabs, but here is an example for opening 2 tabs instead.

There are 2 variables:

1. `counter` for counting how many times the button has been clicked.
2. `sites` This is an array of websites to be open.

Javascript

```
var counter = 0;
var sites = ['http://www.google.nl', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com']; // URLS to open.
function openTab()
{
    counter++;

    var test = document.getElementById("count");
    test.innerHTML = 3-counter;
    if(counter == 3)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++)
        {
            window.open(sites[i]);
        }

        // Reset counter
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

html

```
<div>
    After <span id="count">3</span> click(s) there will be opened 2 tabs<br /><br />
    <button onclick="openTab();">Open</button>
</div>
```

**This is for education only, do not abuse or implement it in your website for spam purposes.**

Comment: Thank you C0dekid. I will try this out in an hour as my computer is a very low percentage.